# Generating random -1 and +1 values in Excel

Tags: excel, random

The `Rand()` function would generate a real number between 0 and 1.
The `Randbetween(-1,1)` would generate either -1, 0, or 1. 
What I want is only -1 or 1.
And what about real numbers between -1 and 1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy:

```
=IF(RAND()<0.5,-1,1)
```

To get the real numbers, use

```
=RAND()*2-1
```

Comment: What if I wanted the real numbers in the interval [-1,1] ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution:

```
=Randbetween(0,1)*2-1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RANDBETWEEN` to generate two values, either 0 or 1, and substitute -1 for 0.

```
=IF(RANDBETWEEN(0,1) = 0, -1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

do rand, if it is more than .5, return 1, if it is less, return -1

```
=IF(RAND()>0.5,1,-1)
```